# Ember.js Route with searchquery causes: UnrecognizedURLError

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-query-params

In my app I have a searchformula with dynamic input fields. The form leads then to the following URL:

```
/trefferliste/?modulId=1&modus=dokument&identnummer=XXX
```

my route definition:

```
this.resource('trefferliste', { 'path' : 'trefferliste/:query' });
```

until this point it works, but when i refresh the page it says: ***UnrecognizedURLError***

in the trefferliste route I load the data with following statement:

```
return this.store.find('trefferliste', params.query);
```

I figured out, that the "?" causes the problem, but I need it for my store find query. So, can someone tell me how to define my route?

UPDATE: Here is a jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nesehuxugi

Steps to reproduce the error:

Push the Button > then refresh the page and look into the console!

some additional informations:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.12.1
ember-template-compiler.js:163 DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.17
ember-template-compiler.js:163 DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.2
```

Comment: Can you setup demo on emberjs.jsbin.com or ember-twiddle.com?

Comment: Here is a jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nesehuxugi  Push the Button, look at the URL and then refresh the page. Look in the console and you see the error!

Comment: I'll give you an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query params instead of dynamic segments, so characters with special meaning to URL schema will be escaped and your application routing will work even on refresh.

URL becomes: `http://app.com#/trefferliste?query=%3FmodulId%3D1%26modus%3Ddokument%26identnummer%3DXXX`, but you have to respect Ember.js and global URL conventions.

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nudogi/3/edit?html,js)

Code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('trefferliste');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.TrefferlisteController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['query'],
  query: null
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({ 
  actions: {
    suche: function() {
      var query = "?modulId=1&modus=dokument&identnummer=XXX";
      this.transitionTo('trefferliste', { queryParams: { query: query } });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: hello daniel,i will try this tomorrow!  thanks & best regards rocki